# Booking hotel (date and guest)

Tags: user-behavior, ux-designer

I have 2 questions, can anyone helps me get the answer

1. When you booking hotel:choose range date, from check-in date to check-out date OR choose check-in date then choose how many nights stay. Which is UX more and why?
2. When you booking hotel, hotel require you enter number of rooms, adults and children. Can we dont require user enter children? it means just enter rooms and guests?

Answer (score 1):

> When you booking hotel:choose range date, from check-in date to check-out date OR choose check-in date then choose how many nights
>   stay. Which is UX more and why?

I would chose between dates and then after they've chosen a date-range I would display number of nights.

Let's say someone is booking more than a week. Monday -> Thursday (the next week) I don't think they want to calculate how many days that is just too book. While it may be easy for you; most people would probably find this annoying or even "impossible"

It's better to let them pick dates, display number of nights and then the total cost.

> When you booking hotel, hotel require you enter number of rooms,
>   adults and children. Can we dont require user enter children? it means
>   just enter rooms and guests?

Most hotels offer smaller beds so they children can sleep in the same room as their parents (usually parent's don't allow lets say 2-3 5-7 olds have their own room). That's why you enter number of children (also they're calculating the costs of breakfast etc.)

If you at your hotel or service and it's customers (hotels) don't care about number of children and just people you can display without number of children.

It won't take up extra space or be annoying for the customers anyway having to fill out number of children if you just default it to 0 anyway.

--
To summarize:

- Pick a date range.
- Have the option to chose number of children, but
  default to 0 so customers only have to fill in number of adults
  (total number of attendees). But if there's a mix between adults and
  children they'll have no problem filling it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer to go for option A or option B, but you can find the best answer from your persona.
If you are looking to improve its UX, you can't just easily ask to change your flow, you must address decisions to your researches.
In this case, I believe for both questions, you could find the answer in your own user study (Persona).
but...
For Question 1: If you don't have any research or even you don't have any data to make a decision, just run a quick A/B Test to make the right decision.
For Question 2: The best way is to ask for the number of rooms and adults, then in the conditions, you could add options for kids.